# Am I the only one who have this problem: While running something like .bat, the "X:\..\..path" often becomes ""X:\..\path and producing errors?

Tags: batch-file

While running something like .bat, the `"X:\..\..path"` often becomes `""X:\..\path` and producing errors. For example, I was installing apktool, then it just appeared this:
`'""C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,`
`operable program or batch file.`
I then copy the command and put one of the double quote to the end, which is like this: `"C:\Program"`
And everything just went smoothly, installation was successful. Then I tried to decode an apk, and the exactly same problem occurred: `'""C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` This time I have no idea how to fix it, it's not like the .bat now, I cannot get the @echo on and copy the last command and edit it. So I am here to ask: If I am the only one who met this? Any way to fix this? Thank you.

My command:

```bash
apktool d test.apk
```

Image of running a decode command : [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6w4rK.png)

`apktool.bat` content:

```bash
@echo off
setlocal
set BASENAME=apktool_
chcp 65001 2>nul >nul

set java_exe=java.exe

if defined JAVA_HOME (
set java_exe="%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe"
)

rem Find the highest version .jar available in the same directory as the script
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
pushd "%~dp0"
if exist apktool.jar (
    set BASENAME=apktool
    goto skipversioned
)
set max=0
for /f "tokens=1* delims=-_.0" %%A in ('dir /b /a-d %BASENAME%*.jar') do if %%~B gtr !max! set max=%%~nB
:skipversioned
popd
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion

rem Find out if the commandline is a parameterless .jar or directory, for fast unpack/repack
if "%~1"=="" goto load
if not "%~2"=="" goto load
set ATTR=%~a1
if "%ATTR:~0,1%"=="d" (
    rem Directory, rebuild
    set fastCommand=b
)
if "%ATTR:~0,1%"=="-" if "%~x1"==".apk" (
    rem APK file, unpack
    set fastCommand=d
)

:load
"%java_exe%" -jar -Duser.language=en -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 "%~dp0%BASENAME%%max%.jar" %fastCommand% %*

rem Pause when ran non interactively
for /f "tokens=2" %%# in ("%cmdcmdline%") do if /i "%%#" equ "/c" pause
```

Comment: Please delete the above comment, I have added it where it belongs, **in your question**. However, as the location `\Program Files...` does not exist in `apktool.bat` or in your submitted command, we need to see the other commands in your own batch file. I will also say that the third party batch file, `apktool.bat` also requires improvements, _feel free to tell the author I said so_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `set "var=value"` for setting string values - this avoids problems caused by trailing spaces. Don't assign a terminal `\`, Space or `"` - build pathnames from the elements - counterintuitively, it is likely to make the process easier. If the syntax `set var="value"` is used, then the quotes become part of the value assigned.

```
set java_exe="%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe"
```

Should be

```
set "java_exe=%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe"
```

(apply this principle throughout your code)

Then, if you require <kbd>"</kbd> anywhere, insert it where it's needed - don't try to include it as part of a variable's value.

This should clean up at least some of your problems.